# How to add search feature in pagination in ngx-datatable?

Tags: angular, ngx-datatable

How can I add a search feature in pagination in ngx datatable? I would like to make it so that there is a search bar at the bottom of my table where if I search 3, it will bring me to the 3rd page. Currently I am able to click the arrows or numbers to navigate to a certain page but I would like to be able to search it as well. So far my template is:

```
<ngx-datatable 
      class="material"
      [limit]="10" 
      [rows]="rows" 
      [rowHeight]="50" 
      [columns]="columns"
      [columnMode]="'force'" 
      [sortType]="'multi'" 
      [headerHeight]="50" 
      [footerHeight]="50">
</ngx-datatable>
```

And the .ts is:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

export interface Data {
  dummyData: string;
}

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {

  public data: Data;
  public columns: any;
  public rows: any;

  constructor(
    private http: HttpClient
  ) {
    
    this.columns = [
      { name: 'Name' },
      { name: 'Gender' },
      { name: 'Company' },
      { name: 'Age' },
      { name: 'Occupation' },
      { name: 'Hobby' },
      { name: 'Colour' },
      { name: 'Flexible' },
      { name: 'Height' },
      { name: 'Experience' },
      { name: 'Colour' },
      { name: 'Flexible' },
      { name: 'Height' },
      { name: 'Experience' },
    ];

    this.http.get<Data>('../../assets/dummyData.json')
      .subscribe((x) => {
        this.rows = x.dummyData;
      });
  }

  ngOnInit() {
  }
}
```

Comment: Maybe this might help https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ngx-datatables-filter-all-columns or at least give you some idea.

Comment: Oh no I meant search the pages (e.g. page 1-9 and I search "8" to get to page 8)

Comment: You can use ngx-pagination package for your table.